# How can I find the following output using a mongo query

Tags: mongodb

How can I find the following output using a mongo query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec387342971ea13815924e0"),
    "fullName" : "pqr",
    "pendingRequest" : [],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec387552971ea13815924e1"),
    "fullName" : "xyz",
    "pendingRequest" : [],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3876f2971ea13815924e2"),
    "fullName" : "abc",
    "pendingRequest" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5ec387342971ea13815924e0"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5ec387552971ea13815924e1"
        }
    ],
}
```

This is my data looks like.
I want to retrieve "fullName" whose "_id" is in the "pendingRequest" array of "abc" user.
I have tried using "$match", "$lookup" stages but didn't get expected output.

Comment: Can you also post a sample output you expect for the posted sample input documents?

Comment: Like in array of "pendingRequest" in "abc" user is having 2 id which are of "pqr" and "xyz" user. So I just want their names as a output. @hhharsha36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To make use of lookup you need to store the "_id" in pending request as ObjectId's.
2. Try following code it will work.

   ```
    db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {fullName: "abc"}
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$pendingRequest"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {from: "so", localField: "pendingRequest._id", foreignField: "_id", as: "a"}
    }
   ])
   ```
3. Also, one more suggestion, it would be better to use pendingRequest as array instead of object array.

   pendingRequest: [ObjectId("5ec387342971ea13815924e0"),ObjectId("5ec387552971ea13815924e1")]